# How can I center align a word(s) in a table?

Tags: alignment

Say I have the table:

```
| TITLE             |
| This is some text |
```

Can I center align the TITLE like so?

```
|       TITLE       |
| This is some text |
```

I've tried using both EasyAlign and Tabular but without much success.

Comment: Can there be whitespace before the first `|` or after the last `|`? I have a simple function that will work if the first and last columns are not whitespace. I can post it if you're desperate. ;)

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I can accept that :) Do you mind sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Per the comments I'm offering this as a very rudimentary solution in case no one has a better suggestion. It's limited and hardly production grade. But OP asked to see it after I offered...*

This function requires that there be no whitespace before or after the framing characters (`|` in the first and last columns of your example). And it only works well with padding made up of spaces (!) ... with tabs it *might* work but only with a fortuitous placement of the tabs. Hey, I'm an `expandtabs` kind of guy, sorry. :)

```
func! CenterEmbedText()
    norm! 0
    let sp1 = searchpos('^\S*\zs\s', 'c')[1]
    let wd1 = searchpos('\S', 'z')[1]
    let sp2 = searchpos('\s\+\S\+$', 'zs')[1]
    let wd2 = searchpos('\s\zs\S', 'z')[1]
    let lm = wd1 - sp1
    let rm = wd2 - sp2
    let mm = abs(rm - lm) / 2
    if rm > lm
        exec 'norm! ' . sp2 . '|' . mm . 'x' . sp1 . '|p'
    elseif rm < lm
        let mm =  (mm == 0) ? 1 : mm
        exec 'norm! ' . sp2 . '|' . mm . "i \<ESC>" . sp1 . '|' . mm . 'x'
    endif
endfunc

nnoremap <silent> <leader>c :call CenterEmbedText()<CR>
```

In the mapping you can replace `<leader>c` with whatever unused key combo you like.

The function simply counts the spaces to the left and right of the text to center (stored in variables `lm` and `rm`) and balances things, if necessary, by deleting `mm` spaces from one side and adding them to the other side.

To use just put the cursor anywhere on the line to modify and enter the mapped key sequence (<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> for me.)

I tested it with text similar to your example and it works fine. Let me know if you have text for which it doesn't work and I'll take a look.

**Update:** I noticed that when center falls between two columns this is inconsistent on whether it uses -1 or +1 as the center and I'll fix when I get a chance.

Comment: Hey man that is great! I do use spaces too and I managed to get around the various limitation by centering the text in a temp line and then moving it and/or adding extra characters afterwards. I see it's not perfect but does the job anyway! Thank you :)

Comment: @jihupona Cool. Glad you found it useful. If you see any issue that you think might be straightforward to fix let me know and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

#### Re-centering with a substitution or "how I learned to abuse regex backtracking"

For giggles you can do this with a `:substitution`:

```
:%s/\v\|\zs(\s*)(.{-})(\s*)\ze\|/\=substitute(submatch(1).submatch(3),'\v(\s*)(\1\s=)','\1'.escape(submatch(2),'&~').'\2','')/g
```

**Overview**:

Capture the text and the leading and trailing characters, spaces in this case. We use a sub-replace-expression to do another substitution to divide up the spaces in half. This balancing act is done via the regex engine's backtracking because math is hard (let's go shopping).

Notes:

- Using very magic, `\v`, to simplify regex. See [`:h 'magic'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27magic%27).
- Using a sub-replace-expression, `\=`. See [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression).
- `{-}` is a non-greedy version of `*`. Similar to `*?` in Perl-speak. See [`:h /\{-`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#E60).
- Learn more about this regex trick here: [An easy way to center text between first and last non-white word in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15844169/438329)
- Using `\zs` & `\ze` to set start and end of matching text
- Possibly use `:keeppatterns` to prevent side-effects.

Probably best to make this into a command:

```
:command! -range -bar CenterCells keeppatterns <line1>,<line2>s/\v\|\zs(\s*)(.{-})(\s*)\ze\|/\=substitute(submatch(1).submatch(3),'\v(\s*)(\1\s=)','\1'.escape(submatch(2),'&~').'\2','')/g
```

For more help see:

- [`:h :s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s)
- [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression)
- [`:h submatch()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#submatch())
- [`:h escape()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#escape())
- [`:h 'magic'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27magic%27)
- [`:h /\{-`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#E60)
- [`:h /\=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C=)
- [`:h /\zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs)
- [`:h :command`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command)

#### Centering with `:Tabularize`

You need to set the start and end of the matches with `\zs` & `\ze`. Use the `c` flag for centering.

```
:Tabularize/|\s*\zs.\{-}\ze\s*|/c1
```

Comment: Wow, I've learned multiple things here, thanks!